# proactive bot leak, posts to wrong session

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Im using the proactive bot template to call a web service from an azure function then interrupt the dialog with a response.

Works great but:

1. sometimes I get a second message appear, as though queue was triggered twice.
2. if two conversations in progress, the message interrupts the wrong conversation.

I think both problems share root cause, does this sound familiar?

My function code:

```
module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
 context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.', 
 myQueueItem);

var request = require('request');

  var options = { method: 'POST',
 url: 'etc',
 qs: { 'api-version': '2.0', details: 'true' },
 headers:
{
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'content-type': 'application/json',
 authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxx' },
body:
{ Inputs:
  { input1:
     { ColumnNames: [ 'UserProblem' ],
       Values: [ [ myQueueItem.text ] ] } },
 GlobalParameters: {} },
json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
 myQueueItem.text = body.Results.output1.value.Values;     

var message = {
        'text': myQueueItem.text,
        'address': myQueueItem.address,
        'reference': 'SPARROW',
    };
    context.done(null, message);
});  };
```

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK? Can you post the code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: using Node, I've added the function code to the original post